# Is ACAccount thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, twitter

Can I share a single `ACAccount` instance between threads? Specifically I would like to create  multiple `TWRequest` objects that are used by different `NSOperationQueue` instances. Those `TWRequest` objects will share a single `ACAccount` instance. Is that safe?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to give more context for what you're talking about. What are `ACAccount`s? `TWRequest`s? More info is necessary to answer your question. Are these classes part of a framework?

Comment: This is for the Twitter framework in iOS 5. Clearly marked in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to say, "no." Firstly, `ACAccount` does not appear on Apple's ["Thread Safe" list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html).  Secondly, I see no explicit mention of thread safety in the reference for either of those classes.  Thirdly, I see that TWRequest appears to be built upon `NSURLConnection` which is designed for use on a run loop (typically the main thread). I see *nothing at all* to indicate that these classes are safe for concurrent use from multiple threads. At best, you should take a thread-confinement approach (i.e. each thread fetches/creates its own copies of these objects and should not pass them between threads.)

Since TWRequest is designed for cooperative/runloop-based operation, I see no reason that you would *need* to do this stuff on a background thread either, FWIW.

So yeah. I'd say, "no."